# Importing C++ dll function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, function, frameworks, mediainfo

I would like to call a function inside MediaInfo.dll.

The function is:

```
const wchar_t*     __stdcall MediaInfo_Option (void* Handle, const
wchar_t* Option, const wchar_t* Value);
```

I have declared it in the c# code in this way:

```
[DllImport("MediaInfo.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] internal
static extern string MediaInfo_Option(IntPtr Handle, string OptionString, string Value);
```

here is the code in which it's called:

```
MediaInfo.MediaInfo_Open(this.h, path);
MediaInfo.MediaInfo_Option(this.Handle, "Complete", "1");
myTextBox.Text = MediaInfo.MediaInfo_Inform(this.h, 0);
MediaInfo.MediaInfo_Close(this.h);
```

The problem is that any c# application compiled with .NET Framework equal or greater than the version 4 crash when calling that function.

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot declare the return type as *string*, the pinvoke marshaller is going to try to release the memory for the native string and that's very unlikely to turn out well.  Use IntPtr instead, recover the string with Marshal.PtrToStringUni().  And kneel down and pray you don't actually have to release the string.

Comment: you are also referencing the 64bit version of MediaInfo.DLL  which may or may not be what you want

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks! Now it works good!

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, shouldn't I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You did not Marshall the wchar_t* of both input and output, you'll get random errors.

There is a [C# binding of MediaInfo](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL.cs) which takes care of all the ugly stuff.
You can use it with a [C# example of MediaInfo](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/Example/HowToUse_Dll.cs).
You may be interested in downloading the [DLL package with a C# example project](http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.82/MediaInfo_DLL_0.7.82_Windows_x64_WithoutInstaller.7z).